# no module named '_sqlite3' после установки питона из исходников

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.8

Есть сервер на Ubentu 16.04 по этому [Гайду](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/), поставил python3.8 на неё.
При попытке импорта модуля sqlite3 вылетает

> No module named '_sqlite3'

Как исправить?

полный текст ошибки

```
(venv) nso@goldconig:~/coldconfig$ python3 manage.py runserver 10.233.204.43:8001
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/nso/coldconfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

UPD.
Если вы как и я, уже поставили питон и у вас нет этой зависимости, то:
Выполните команду: sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
После чего выполните все шаги из гайда начиная с

> cd /tmp
>   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
>   и т.д.

Если вы ещё не ставили или удалили, просто в команду

> sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget

добавьте libsqlite3-dev через пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ответах на [похожий вопрос на английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210664/240613) написано, что нужно выполнить `apt install libsqlite3-dev` и поставить Python заново.